# Cheerio WebScraping Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, cheerio

I want to scrape a webpage and get all the links out with (if present) a thumbnail or image within the 'a' tag.

I'm able to get the links, but not sure how to grab the img > src value within the current a tag im iterating over.

```
const cheerio = require('cheerio')
const request = require('request')
const throttledRequest = require('throttled-request')(request)
throttledRequest.configure({ requests: 18, milliseconds: 1000 })

let o = {
  linksOut: []
}

const scrapeLinksOut = (o, body) => {
  if (body) {
    let $ = cheerio.load(body)

    $('a').map(function () {
      let link = $(this).attr('href')
      // I want to get the img url within the a tag for the current iteration
      let thumbnail = $(this).//img > src

      o.linksOut.push( {
        link: link,
        thumbnail: thumbnail
      })
    })
  } else {
   // something else
  }
}

const scrape = (() => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    throttledRequest({
      url: 'https://www.ibm.com/us-en',
      followAllRedirects: true,
      timeout: 30000
    }, (err, res, body) => {
      scrapeLinksOut(o, body)
      return resolve(o)
    })
  }) 
})

scrape()
  .then((res) => {
    res.linksOut.forEach((obj) => {
     console.log(obj);
   })
  })
  .catch((err) => console.log(err))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/) to get the `img` element, and then [attr()](https://api.jquery.com/attr/) to get its src.

`$(this).find('img').attr('src')`

Comment: Not every `a` on the page has an `img` child, right? For the `a` tags that do not have a child `img`, that will return undefined.

Comment: Correct, not all of them have an img tag, but the ones that do are still undefined for some reason

Comment: My bad, i actually am getting some img values now. But they are all the same string though

Comment: Here's a demonstration: https://codepen.io/mistval/pen/mdmqbQj

Answer (score 0):

I wrote up a quick solution that hopefully solves your problem. I tested it out on my machine and it works for me.

```
$('a').map(function () {

...
    let thumbnail = $(this).html();
    thumbnail = cheerio.parseHTML(thumbnail);

    if (thumbnail!== null && thumbnail.length > 0 && //Ensure link has an image
    thumbnail[0].attribs !== undefined && 
    thumbnail[0].attribs.src !== undefined) {
        thumbnail = thumbnail[0].attribs.src; //The image URL
    }

...

});
```

```
const scrapeLinksOut = (o, body) => {
  if (body) {
    let $ = cheerio.load(body)

    $('a').map(function () {
      let link = $(this).attr('href')
     
      let thumbnail = $(this).html();
      thumbnail = cheerio.parseHTML(thumbnail)


      if (thumbnail !== null && thumbnail.length > 0 && thumbnail[0].attribs !== undefined && thumbnail[0].attribs.src !== undefined) {
        thumbnail = thumbnail[0].attribs.src
      } else {
        thumbnail = null
      }

      o.linksOut.push( {
        link: link,
        thumbnail: thumbnail
      })
    })
  } else {
    o.linksOut.push(links)
  }
}
```

this logs:

```
null
null
null
[object Object]
[object Object]
[object Object]
[object Object]
[object Object]
[object Object]
[object Object]
[object Object]
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
```

Comment: I am getting object Object. Is this img going to be linked to the a tag that the current iteration is on?

Comment: The above code should've extracted the URL from the object. But you can try printing the object to the console (e.g., console.log(object)) to see what it's returning and whether or not the link is included in it, and if it's the proper link as well.

Comment: I logged it to the console and got :
[object Object]
[object Object]
[object Object]
[object Object]
null
null
null

Comment: loggin just the thumbnail[0].attribs i get :


[Object: null prototype] {
  focusable: 'false',
  preserveAspectRatio: 'xMidYMid meet',
  xmlns: 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg',
  fill: 'currentColor',
  src: '[object Object]',
  width: '20',
  height: '20',
  viewBox: '0 0 20 20',
  'aria-hidden': 'true',
  class: 'bx--card__cta'
}

Answer (score 0):

This seemed to work out. Links and images match up.

```
const scrapeLinksOut = (o, body) => {
  if (body) {
    let $ = cheerio.load(body);

    $('a').map(function () {
      let thumbnail;
      let link = $(this).attr('href');

      $(this)
        .find('img')
        .map(function (i, img) {
          thumbnail = $(img).attr('src');
        });

      if (thumbnail !== undefined) {
        o.linksOut.push({
          link: link,
          thumbnail: thumbnail,
        });
      }
    });
  } else {
    // something else
  }
};
```